# Can't make the Multimedia keys work in LXDE

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, lxde

I've tried to edit the configuration file in `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` however the changes don't take effect, i still can't use the keys.

[The LXDE wiki](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE%3aQuestions) shows that after finding that my keyboard sends the correct standardized keyboard events i should go and edit the file to my liking, the keyboard does send the correct events and the keys are properly identified yet nothing happens.

Since LXDE doesn't come with a sound preferences option i have installed `xfce4-mixer`. I too have a netbook running Lubuntu and its media keys are working fine, i don't know if what i installed has had something to do here?.

I also installed `xfce4-volumed volume keys daemon` from synaptic but to no avail, still nothing.

How can i make the multimedia keys of my keyboard ( Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 1000) work in LXDE with `xfce4-mixer`

**Edit**: Here is my [lxde-rc.xml](http://pastebin.com/1YkcHtEz) file

I've commented the line `OnlyShowIn=XFCE:` in  `/etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-volumed.desktop` and now i get a notification when pressing the Volume keys however it doesn't have any effect on the audio output. The Play/Pause, Stop, etc. Keys still don't work.

I also tried to use the commands my XML file has, i.e. `amixer sset Master 3%+` and i get this:

```
  Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 5 [8%] [-59.00dB] [on]
```

Using the command again raises this value  `Mono: Playback 5 [8%] [-59.00dB] [on]` to `Mono: Playback 7 [11%] [-57.00dB] [on]` but no audible effect is noticed.

Comment: On a different note I believe `xfce4-volumed` is XFCE only startup job. Make sure its running in lxde as well.

Comment: basically comment the the line `showonlyin: XFCE` in `/etc/xdg/autstart/xfce4-volumed.desktop`. I think `ps aux | grep xfce4-volumed` would say if process is running or not.

Comment: @fossfreedom Done editing the question, i do have pulseaudio installed, killing it causes the volume to drop in dB even when the volume control slider is at the max.

Comment: Uri - just confirming what I think you said - killing pulseaudio and then running the amixer commands manually changes the volume correctly.  Having pulseaudio and running the amixer commands manually does not change the volume - hence it is pulseaudio that is clashing with LXDE ALSA Audio.  What happens if you just uninstall pulseaudio and reboot.

Comment: Killing pulseaudio makes the volume sort of drop in dB, and then if i use the amixer commands to raise the volume they don't do anything. But i will uninstall it and see what happens.

Comment: hmm - I've tried to run the amixer commands manually on my LXDE/oneiric unity setup - it works as expected - volume goes up and down.  Any details on what your sound card is? How does xfce4-mixer see your sound-card? What "select controls" have you got enabled in xfce4-mixer?

Comment: I'm using the HDMI output of a Radeon HD card, xfce4-mixer detects it as HDMI output RV740 and only the master channel is available.

Comment: possibly you need to specify the soundcard that amixer needs to run i.e. `amixer -c hw:N sset ...` where N is the card number for your HDMI output - find this via `cat /proc/asound/cards`

Comment: I have reinstalled the whole OS due another inconvenience, now i'm using XFCE instead of LXDE so my Volume keys work fine, thank you though for the help.

Comment: ok - post your comment as an answer so that you can accept and close the question.